# how to get complete impex file for a table in hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

We have one table called CustomerPreference which has some 20+ columns and 800K records. i am trying to get the complete impex [with all the columns like all 20+ columns in the impex definition] but i don't have all the columns in the sample impex in the projectdata or essentialdata but i need to load the data in that table for one defect.

Need to know whether there is anyway or any tool in hybris can get me the complete impex statement for that table? Thanks in advance and Appreciate your help.

Comment: You can upload your data from csv file to Hybris using `Hot Folder`. You need to map your column value with the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the hmc (hybris management console, by default via http://localhost:9001/hmc/hybris?wid=MC0x0) you can go to

System -> Tools -> Script Generator

and click on the "Generate" button to have a script generated that will allow to export the whole type system. 
You will then have to manually select the parts of the generated script that contains the types (and relationships) that you want to actually export. 
But this will give you some sort of a head start for a script.

Once you have the script ready you can test it in the hac (http://localhost:9001) and click on

Console -> ImpEx Export and paste your script in there to do the export (I think) .. or use an impex cronjob to execute your script..

Hope this helps a bit.. :)

Comment: sure.. glad I could help. :)